# SqlMetadataStore database password? (Sync Framework)

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

The SqlMetadataStore from the Sync Framework implements a MetadataStore using the Sql Compact Edition.

To understand better the implementation I'm trying to open the store with Management Studio (or even the Server Explorer in Visual Studio). But it asks me for a password. What password should I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it asks for a password because it was converted from SQL CE 3.1.

Try just a blank password. That's what works for me.

Comment: ha... was that obvious eh? Thanks much! :-)